# How do I get the bot to write user's name

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

This is the code, I want it to write user's name and then auction word (p.s I am new to this)

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const channel = client.channels.cache.get('889459156782833714');


client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
})

client.on("message", msg => {
    var message = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#FF0000')
        .setTitle() // want user's name + "Auction"
        .addField('Golden Poliwag', 'Very Pog', true)
        .setImage('https://graphics.tppcrpg.net/xy/golden/060M.gif')
        .setFooter('Poliwag Auction')
  
    if (msg.content === "d.test") {
        msg.reply(message)
    }
})
```

Comment: What user's username? The one who sent the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the user's username by using `msg.author.tag`. So. the way to use the user's tag in an embed would be:

```js
const { MessageEmbed, Client } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client();

const channel = client.channels.cache.get("889459156782833714");

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on("message", (msg) => {
    var message = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#FF0000")
        .setTitle(`${msg.author.tag} Auction`)
        .addField("Golden Poliwag", "Very Pog", true)
        .setImage("https://graphics.tppcrpg.net/xy/golden/060M.gif")
        .setFooter("Poliwag Auction");
    if (msg.content === "d.test") {
        msg.reply(message);
    }
});
```

Comment: Wrong, `msg.user` does not exist

Comment: Sorry, accidentally typed it. It should be `msg.author.tag`. I have edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read the [discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/), almost all you need to interact with Discord API is from there.

1. You can't control the bot if you don't login to it. Get the bot's token from   [Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) and login to your bot by adding `client.login('<Your token goes here>')` in your project.
2. You can't get the channel if it's not cached in the client. You need to fetch it by using `fetch()` method from client's channels manager:

```js
const channel = await client.channels.fetch('Channel ID goes here');
```

P/s: await is only available in async function

3. `message` event is deprecated if you are using **discord.js v13**. Please use `messageCreate` event instead.
4. You are able to access user who sent the message through `msg` object: `msg.author`. If you want their tag, you can get the `tag` property from user: `msg.author.tag`, or  username: `msg.author.username` or even user ID: `msg.author.id`. For more information about discord message class read [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Message).
5. The reply options for message is not a message. You are trying to reply the message of the author with another message which is wrong. Please replace the reply options with an object that includes `embeds`:

```js
msg.reply({ 
    embeds: [
        // Your array of embeds goes here
    ]
});
```

From all of that, we now have the final code:

```js
const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client();

client.on("ready", () => {console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)});

client.on("messageCreate", async (msg) => {
    const channel = await client.channels.fetch('889459156782833714');
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#FF0000')
        .setTitle(`${msg.author.tag} Auction`)
        .addField('Golden Poliwag','Very Pog',true)
        .setImage('https://graphics.tppcrpg.net/xy/golden/060M.gif')
        .setFooter('Poliwag Auction');
    if (msg.content === "d.test") {
        msg.reply({
            embeds: [ embed ],
        });
    }
});

client.login('Your bot token goes here');
```

Now your bot can reply to command user with an rich embed.

Comment: The OP did define Discord, but didn't format the question correctly. Also, you don't need to fetch the channel unless you are sharding, since it's always cached. You actually *can* control a bot without being logged in, but that's raw API requests... Note the OP might also be using v12, meaning the embed send syntax is correct

Comment: @MrMythical yeah so I just say that **if** he's using discord.js. And I suggest him to upgrade because discord.js v12 will stop working on April 30th.

Comment: Also he's using discord.js so we help him in discord.js so he can easily understand.

Comment: Thanks guys , I updated my discord version to V13

Comment: @ShivangGoswami nice, make sure to read the change logs from v12 to v13 [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#before-you-start)